# ld: framework not found FacebookSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, facebook-ios-sdk

[image]ld: framework not found FacebookSDK

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I am deleted old Facebook frameworks and now am using cocoa pods when i compile the project i face that error, i change the frameWorkSearchPath also but no solution any suggestions ?? Thank you.

Comment: Did you get answer to your question.If yes please tell me how to solve?

Comment: copy your framework and paste it on documents. Then drag and drop to your project from documents.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project target -> Build settings, search for 'facebook' and you should see the framework come up in `Other Linker Flags`. Remove it with the preceding `-framework` item and you should be good!